# Como obtener datos con AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

En el primer componente HomeCreen pongamos que almaceno un string **AAA**, pulso el Boton *save* y el texto se almacena usando AsyncStorage. Cuando pulso navegar, voy al otro componente que es similar y, como he almacenado previamente **AAA** me aparece el alert() con eso mismo. Ahora bien, si en este segundo componente hago lo mismo que en el primero pero guardo la cadena ***BBB***, cuando navegue al componente anterior me deberia de salir otra vez el alert() con los nuevos datos.

Mi duda es, se puede volver a crear el componente para que se ejecute como si fuese la primera vez, o se pueden obtener los datos de AsyncStorage de forma dinamica al volver a dicho componente? O alguna forma de refrescar los datos el navegar a ese componente

Codigo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
        import { AsyncStorage, Button, TextInput,  View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, FlatList, StyleSheet, Image, ImageBackground, StatusBar} from 'react-native'
        import { LinearGradient } from 'expo'
        import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'


        class ProfileScreen extends Component {

            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    text: ''
                }
            }

            componentWillMount() {
                this.retrieveData()
            }

            saveData = async () => {
                try {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem('MY_DATA', JSON.stringify(this.state.text))
                }catch(error) {
                        console.log(error.message)
                }
            }

            retrieveData = async () => {
                try{
                    const MY_DATA = await AsyncStorage.getItem('MY_DATA')
                    alert(MY_DATA)
                    this.setState({text: MY_DATA})
                }catch(error) {
                    console.log(error.message)
                }
            }

                navigate() {

                 console.log('navigating')
                const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
               navigate('Home')

            }



            render() {
                return (
                    <View>
                        <TextInput style = {{width: '100%', height: 50, borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 100, backgroundColor: 'pink'}} onChangeText = {text => this.setState({text: text})}/>
                        <View style = {{width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop: 40}}>
                            <Button title = "Save" onPress = {() => this.saveData()} />
                            <Button title = "Retrieve data" onPress = {() => this.retrieveData()} />
                        </View>
                        <Text>TEXT: {this.state.text}</Text>
                        <View style = {{width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop: 40}}>
                            <Text onPress = {() => this.navigate()}>Navigate</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                )
            }
        }


        class HomeScreen extends Component {
            static navigationOptions = {
                header: null
            }
            constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
              this.state = {
                  isOpen: false,
                  text: ''
              };
            }

            componentWillMount() {
                this.retrieveData()
            }


            toggle() {
                this.setState({
                  isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
                });
            }

            updateMenuState(isOpen) {
                this.setState({ isOpen });
            }

            navigate() {

                 console.log('navigating')
                const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
               navigate('Profile')

            }


            saveData = async () => {
                try {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem('MY_DATA', JSON.stringify(this.state.text))
                }catch(error) {
                        console.log(error.message)
                }
            }

            retrieveData = async () => {
                try{
                    const MY_DATA = await AsyncStorage.getItem('MY_DATA')
                    alert(MY_DATA)
                    this.setState({text: MY_DATA})
                }catch(error) {
                    console.log(error.message)
                }
            }

          render() {

            return (

                <View style={styles.containerMenu}>
                    <StatusBar barStyle = 'light-content' />
                        <View style = {styles.container}>
                            <ScrollView style = {[{width: '100%', height: '100%'}]}>
                                <View>
                                    <TextInput style = {{width: '100%', height: 50, borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 100}} onChangeText = {text => this.setState({text: text})}/>
                                    <View style = {{width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop: 40}}>
                                        <Button title = "Save" onPress = {() => this.saveData()} />
                                        <Button title = "Retrieve data" onPress = {() => this.retrieveData()} />
                                    </View>
                                    <Text>TEXT: {this.state.text}</Text>
                                    <View style = {{width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop: 40}}>
                                    <Text onPress = {() => this.navigate()}>Navigate</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </ScrollView>               
                        </View>
                </View>        

            );
          }
        }

        export default class App extends Component {    
            render() {
                return (
                    <RootStack/>
                )
            }
        }

        const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
          {
            Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
            Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},



          },
          {
            initialRouteName: 'Home',
            navigationOptions: {
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(167,167,167)',
              },
              headerTintColor: '#fff',
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
              },
              header: null
            },
          }
        );


        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
            container: {
                flex: 1,
                width: 320,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            },


            button: {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 20,
                padding: 10,
            },
            caption: {
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                alignItems: 'center',
            },
            containerMenu: {
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
            },
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te hace falta es poder escuchar los eventos de navegación y así poder ejecutar el método `retrieveData` en el evento `onWillFocus` o en el `onDidFocus`, en vez de en el `componentWillMount`. ([referencia](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle))

Comment: funciona a la perfeccion !! :D